# How to access a particular log entry based on its token?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to write a python script which will retrieve new log entries and save the token of the last/latest entry. This token will be used in the next run and logs after that token-entry will be retrieved and so on.

So far I have this:

```
from google.cloud.logging import Client

projectName = 'my_project'

myFilter = 'resource.type = "cloudsql_database" AND log_id("cloudsql.googleapis.com/mysql.err") AND timestamp>="2021-04-20T00:00:00Z"'

client = Client(project=projectName)
entries = client.list_entries(filter_=myFilter)

fd = open("log_entries.txt", "w")
for entry in entries:
    print(entry)
    fd.write(str(entry))

fd.close()
```

Sample output entry:

```
TextEntry(
log_name='projects/my_project/logs/cloudsql.googleapis.com%2Fmysql.err',
labels=None, 
insert_id='s=90fe0e477e6e4e6e8e5017468exxxxxx;
    i=1c31xxx;
    b=c42a243698784ef88f55dfe5a4xxxxxx;
    m=53c40845xxx;
    t=5c03646e67xxx;
    x=be3568664236fxxx-0-0@a1',
severity='INFO', 
http_request=None, 
timestamp=datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 20, 2, 50, 33, 830602, tzinfo=<UTC>), 
resource=Resource(type='cloudsql_database', 
labels={'region': 'us-east4', 'database_id': 'my_project:my_instance_id', 'project_id': 'my_project'}), 
trace=None, 
span_id=None, 
trace_sampled=None, 
source_location=None, 
operation=None, 
logger=<google.cloud.logging_v2.logger.Logger object at 0x0000025FA3XXXXXX>, 
payload="2021-04-20T02:50:33.830224Z 63149802 [Note] Aborted connection 63149802 to db: 'my_db' user: 'my_user' host: 'ip_address' (Got an error reading communication packets)"
)
```

As you can see, there is no such value as a token number that can be passed to list_entries method. I'm not sure if list_entries is the correct method to use in my case. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Token will be provided only if there is more results than can be shown in the response.

Make sure there is more logs, set `pageSize` field to a number lower than 50 (that's the default) and test the API [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/entries/list).
If you still don't receive the token, update the question with the results.